# Removing duplicates from pandas dataframe containing json string

Tags: pandas

[image]I have a dataframe with one of the column containing json string as such {'1':105, '2':105, '3':110} in each cell.
When I try to remove duplicates doing df.drop_duplicates(subset=['prices'],keep='last')
It returns an error. I have no issue putting other columns in the dataframe as subset to remove duplicates. But I cant do it with this column in this format. Any idea?

Comment: what error is it?

Comment: what is the result of `print(df3.columns)` ? Seems you have preceding space in the name of `prices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `.drop_duplicates` on a dict type, that's why it gives `unhashable type dict` error. You can do:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'prices': [{'1':54, '2':22, '3':12}, 
                              {'1':54, '2':22, '3':12},
                              {'1':44, '2':41, '3':11}],
                   'flag':[1,2,3]})

# remove duplicates
df  = (pd.concat([df, df.prices.apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['1','2','3'], keep='last')
       .drop(['1','2','3'], axis=1))

                        prices  flag
1  {'1': 54, '2': 22, '3': 12}     2
2  {'1': 44, '2': 41, '3': 11}     3
```

The only trick here is to convert the dict into a data frame using `df.prices.apply(pd.Series)`.